# How do I filter the array?

Tags: php

I am having trouble trying to show that certain numbers (product numbers) exist in an associative array. When I try this code, I always get "false".Please check the below array example.

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [areaid] => 1
        [area] => Fan
        [business] => ["51","53"]
        [city] => 4
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [areaid] => 2
        [area] => Manchester
        [business] => ["51","53"]
        [city] => 4
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [areaid] => 3
        [area] => Battery Park
        [business] => ["53"]
        [city] => 4
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [areaid] => 3
        [area] => Battery Park
        [business] => ["52"]
        [city] => 4
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [areaid] => 3
        [area] => Battery Park
        [business] => ["51","53"]
        [city] => 4
    )
```

)

I want to show result like this

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [areaid] => 1
        [area] => Fan
        [business] => ["51","53"]
        [city] => 4
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [areaid] => 2
        [area] => Manchester
        [business] => ["51","53"]
        [city] => 4
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [areaid] => 3
        [area] => Battery Park
        [business] => ["53","52","51"]
        [city] => 4
    )
```

)

Anybody help me to show this result.

Comment: what is the rule of filtering in your case?

Comment: This is an array of objects . What  exactly are you searching for in the array . It is not clear

Comment: Look like he is trying to group businesses by the area

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, you are trying to group the businesses based on the area?

Try this code:

```
$groupedBusinesses = array();

foreach ($areas as $area) {
    if (array_key_exists($area->areaid, $groupedBusinesses)) {        
        $groupedBusinesses[$area->areaid]->business = 
            array_merge($groupedBusinesses[$area->areaid]->business, $area->business);
    } else {
        $groupedBusinesses[$area->areaid] = $area
    }    
}
```

This will check if the area is already in the list. If it is not, it will be added. If it is, only the businesses will be added to the list.

Comment: Thank you for your help.I have done few changes to your code and it's working.

Comment: Can you please accept this answer then, if it solved your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you need new objects in your result-array maybe this can help:

```
$result = array();
$area   = array();
$i      = 0;
foreach ($array as $key => $obj) {
    if (!in_array($obj->area, $area)) {
        $result[$i]         = new Product($obj->areaid, $obj->area, $obj->business, $obj->city);
        $area[$obj->area]   = $i;
        $i++; 
    } else {
        $result[$area[$obj->area]]->addBusiness($obj->business);
    }
}



class Product {

    public $areaid;
    public $area;
    public $business;
    public $city;

    __construct($areaid, $area, $business, $city) {
        $this->areaid       = $areaid;
        $this->area         = $area;
        $this->business     = $business;
        $this->city         = $city;
    }

    public function addBusiness($int) {
        $this->business[] = $int;
    }
}
```

It will check if the result already contains an entry of this area.
If it does it adds the business-value to the array.
If not ut will create a new object in a new place of the result-array.